# Correct way of dynamically binding a tailwind classes in vuejs3/nuxtjs3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

does someone of you know, what the correct way of dynamically binding the `content` tailwind class in vuejs3/nuxtjs3 is? Let's assume, that `const isExpanded = true`

```
<h1 :class="{'after:content-[`:`]' : isExpanded}">Hello</h1>
```

I have tried it with backticks (`) but it ain't working.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\` to escape the inner apostrophes `'` so they don't prematurely close the outer string

```html
<h1 :class="{'after:content-[\'_↗\']' : isExpanded}">Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, [this solution currently has problems with Tailwind](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8119), because according to the developers, Tailwind processes the source files ["rather as raw text"](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/10245#issuecomment-1372054412).

Answer (score 1):

As one of the solutions, instead of binding CSS classes to an object, you can [bind to an array](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style#binding-to-arrays), as in the example:

```html
<h1 :class="[isExpanded ? `after:content-[':']` : ``]">Hello</h1>
```